# Open ended questions

Tags: discussion

We seem to have quite a lot of questions that don't scope the question well. In many cases this leads us to ask for clarification and the clarification happening in comments. Comments are not permanent.

Please ask the OP to edit the question to reflect the new info. If the question mutates too much encourage them to ask a new question. Or do you disagree with this?

Also should we try to refrain answering questions based on wild guesses?

Comment: I agree questions should be asked to OP when the question is unclear. But sometime, what seems to be wild guesses to some are consistent patterns or typical questions to others. Precision can be added in the answer when OP doesn't know terms. There's always the downvote available for answers that don't make sense and OP too can re-edit after seeing answers are not on target. I will add an ironic comment here: Looking at older "unanswered" questions, it's unfortunate there's so many answers (or half answers) in the comments actually! They can't even be downvoted or accepted.

Comment: @go-junta I think anybody can go and convert those to answers. Im more concerned of the amount of questions that are not interesting to anybody and they are left unanswered and unclosed.

Comment: Joojaa, if the person asking left additional info in the comments then why aren't you editing the question to include the info and then flagging the comment as obsolete?

Comment: @Ryan I think that is what he is asking about

Comment: ...The irony of it all

Comment: @Ryan because I can not turn insinuated hints into proper questions?